# Blender 2.78c Cycles particles change color by age

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

**Thank you for your time reader!**

I want to change particle material colors by their age.
All threads and accepted answers I found dont work for me.

The setup I found in other threads is this:
[image]

The color ramp works.
If I switch the colors the particles become white:
[image]

**After some trial and error it feels like no values are coming out of the particle info node.**
For example if I turn the divide value up/down - nothing changes at all.
If I take an "add" node I can see clearly that all particles change independent from their age.

Does someone have an advice for me?
Even a method to see what (if at all) values come out of the particle info node would help me.

Thank you a lot for your precious time in advance :)

**Blend file:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what's going on, from [Blender Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/particle_info.html) about **Particle Info Node**:

> This node currently only supports parent particles, info from child
>   particles is not available.

So your only option is to turn off **Particle Children** and crank up **Particle Number** to make it 'similar'.

Also if you turn on Parents in Particle Render section some of them will be white but only a few.

[image: Final]

I've checked also in Blender 2.79RC2 but it's not working there either.

Comment: AWESOME! thank you so much! RTFM again... ^^

Comment: Yeah, I've read it after I've struggled with every option connected to the topic. I've just needed confirmation in source ;)